# ACL2 Bridge worker thread throws undefined function exception

Tags: acl2

I'm trying to write a binding to the Centaur ACL2-Bridge.  So far, I can start the bridge with the following sequence:

1. `cd books`
2. `sudo acl2`
3. `acl2 !> (include-book centaur/bridge/acl2/top)`
4. `acl2 !> (bridge::start "Users/Brian/Desktop/acl2server")`

Having that now, sending a command over produces the error:

```
Bridge: bridge-worker-1: Uncaught error in worker thread: 
  Undefined function ACL2::HL-HSPACE-INIT called with arguments () .
```

Perhaps this is a compilation error, or a bug in the system, I'm not yet sure.  `acl2 --version` yields `Version 1.10-dev-r16020M-trunk  (DarwinX8664)`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you have to run bridge in the ACL2(h) extension to get the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It saved me quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks -- I'm the author of the ACL2 bridge, and I did not realize that it had this bug until I saw your question and answer.  It should be easy to fix this, and I'll do so in the development version.